# ms-access VBA, can't unlock locked project

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I`m trying to edit a project in MS-access VBA. If I right click on the project and choose Properties , VBA shows a popup: Project is unviewable.

[image]

I cant even get to the screen to unlock anything or enter the unlock password. The file is a MDB file.

How should I go about solving this?

Comment: your question is unclear now. Where do you choose properties? in Access main window, or VBA editor? Please add a screenshot of the issue. Did you created that file, or received it from somebody else?

Comment: I added a screenshot. I click properties in VBA editor. The file has been inherited. The company that made it for us is bankrupt. The source MDB were lost due to a crypto virus

Comment: Sorry to state the obvious, it is locked to protect code from being altered or copied. If you have no access to original files, or password, you may simply be out of luck.

Comment: I dont want to copy or alter code. I just want to link the right references in VBA so this application will work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by opening the MDB in a Hex editor and replace DBS with DBx.
This way I was able to remove the lock.